# Why does Oracle convert function convert an accented "e" to a "c"?

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

In Oracle 12.1, the following query...

```
select convert(N'è','US7ASCII','EE8MSWIN1250') from dual;
```

Returns "c".  I was hoping for an "e".

Why is this?  I am not well-versed in character set issues.

Comment: `e` you get with `select convert(N'è','US7ASCII','WE8ISO8859P1') from dual;`.  Just guessing;)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber The problem I am facing is that the source system seems to support a broader set of characters and any one Oracle character set has. If I switch to WE8ISO8859P1, for example, I cannot convert the ñ character.

Comment: What do you get from `DUMP(N'è', 1016)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`N'è'` is 0x00E8 in UTF-16, so those bytes are your raw input to the CONVERT function. The source charset is EE8MSWIN1250, so Oracle assumes that you want 0xE8 in that codepage.

In [the EE8MSWIN1250 codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250), 0xE8 maps to č; if you convert that to ASCII, the closest match is "c".

Similar with your other examples - ï = 0xEF, which is ď in EE8MSWIN1250.

Honestly, I'm surprised that these returned anything - an awful lot of the charset conversions I try with CONVERT just don't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why. But, [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions041.htm#SQLRF00620) says

> For complete correspondence in character conversion, **it is essential that the destination character set contains a representation of all the characters defined in the source character set.** Where a character does not exist in the destination character set, a replacement character appears

```
SQL> select convert(N'è','US7ASCII','EE8MSWIN1250') from dual;
                    ----  --------   ------------
C                   char  destination    source charset
-
c
```

Apparently, US7ASCII doesn't contain all characters from EE8MSWIN1250 character set; does it? Replacement character for 'è' (when those two character sets are involved) seems to be `c`, so that's what you got.

Comment: It seems that `'è'` does **not** exists in the [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) character set, I can confirm for *Czech* language. In [WE8ISO8859P1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) this character exists and the conversion works fine. See comment above.

Comment: Aha! Makes sense, @Marmite!

Comment: The problem I am facing is that the source system seems to support a broader set of characters and any one Oracle character set has.  If I switch to WE8ISO8859P1, for example, I cannot convert the ñ character.

Comment: Usually the replacement character is a ?.  For example, if you try to convert ñ using WE8ISO8859P1, you get a ?.  Also, the Oracle documentation for the `CONVERT` function shows ? as the replacement character.  What I am seeing for EE8MSWIN1250 is different than that, I think.  E.g., è maps to "c" but ì maps to "e" and ï maps to ï maps to "d".  If these were all just missing, why would they map to different characters?

Comment: Character codes are *evil* @MatthewMcPeak what should I say more?